# Why can't I log in to the status page tomcat or manager app page in tomcat from a clean install?

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat7, catalina

Why can't I log in to the status page tomcat or manager app page in tomcat from a clean install?

So I go to get a tomcat version like here :http://mirror.olnevhost.net/pub/apache/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.92/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.92-windows-x86.zip

This is windows 32 bit, I unzip the thing and place it into my custom app's tomcat folder (renaming it from apache-tomcat-7.0.92 to just tomcat)

Then I install the tomcat7 service to windows services.msc using "service.bat install" command and then start it in the services.msc

I go to localhost:8080 and getr the main page that states tomcat is installed ... then when I try to click on the status page to login it won't allow...

I configured the tomcat-users xml file and triple checked all settings, even restarted server and restarted service etc

but it won't let me login no matter what?!?!?!

1) anyone can duplicate this, since I'm doing this from clean install

2) only thing is I'm putting it under a different root directory but I cannot imagine that would make a difference, I haven't changed anything upon clean install

Surely this cannot be broken like this and must be simple something that I somehow missed but I can't see how

Comment: 1. Are you the one who posted a very similar question on the tomcat-users mailing list? If yes, then the additional answers there provided quite a good hint as to where your problem is.
2. Instead of asserting that you triple checked and did everything right, please post your actual content/configuration here (edit your question). We can't help you if you just state that you did everything right.

Comment: see https://pastebin.com/xebjnpSA

Comment: That's not an answer to any of the questions that I've stated above. And you don't mention `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory` anywhere above. Do you need help with this? But anyways, again: Please edit your question with the information that I've asked for in my first comment.

Comment: ...as the same stacktrace appeared on the tomcat mailing list, I'm assuming that you posted the same problem there (e.g. this answers my question 1 from the first comment under this question). Please note [this post on crossposting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site). Thank you